# iOS8 Landscape Oriantaion Issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8, landscape

I am using iOS8 landscape mode,but the screen landscape but the content is shown as portrait.I also make sure that only Landscape left and right is selected in build>setting. Please help me to solve the issue.Please check the attached screen shot.
[image]

Comment: upvote my answer if it is fixed

Comment: can you give some more detail or screen shot of your xib

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the constraints for the view.If you did not set the constraints view will get disturb.
Add top constraint, bottom constraint, left constraint and right constraint.

Comment: the parrot colour is the view.and I set background colour for the view.This is the only view in xib.so can't set the constraint on it

Comment: even if only 1 view is there you have to set constraint.select view and set to prefered constraints or suggested constraints.

Comment: ok,I tried but can't able to impose the constraint.Noting can be selected in constraint window.I put a single view and run the app.

Comment: Can you please brief me about how to impose constraint

Comment: I put a uiview in the super view and impose constraint on that.But the result is same.I think it ignore the landscape .

Comment: @TarunSachdeva select view and select reset to suggested constraints which is available option.I am able to see it in my xcode.. By faith it may work

Comment: Yes I click reset to selected constraint.But again bro not able to impose constraint.

Comment: Hello,Please help me on resolving that issue I still face that problem.